# How to access computer connected through usb tethering?

Tags: networking, routing

Here is my network setup: My android mobile(192.168.0.100) is connected to a WiFi router (192.168.0.1). I have enabled USB tethering on the mobile for internet access on my desktop (192.168.42.189). Also from my connection, the gateway is 192.168.42.129. So now we can infer the following from all these data:

```
Router IP: 192.168.0.1
Mobile's IP (for WiFi interface): 192.168.0.100
Mobile's IP (for USB interface): 192.168.42.129
Desktop's IP: 192.186.42.189
```

I tried adding the **route** : **Subnet** 192.168.42.0 with **mask** 255.255.255.0 and the **gateway** as 192.168.0.100.

I can ping the router from my desktop, but I cannot ping my desktop from the router or any other WiFi router connected device

Why cannot I access the desktop, even though I have added the route?

Answer (score 0):

The route you added is unnecessary as you get a "free" route just because the USB's interface is set to 192.168.42.189/24 (/24 is a shortcut for 255.255.255.0).

> I can ping the router from my desktop, but I cannot ping my desktop from the router or any other WiFi router connected device

Your phone is acting as a second router, and won't forward unsolicited incoming traffic to devices behind it (e.g. your desktop) unless you forward ports on it - just like your WiFi router.  You can do this with a utility that changes your phone's `iptables` configuration, if your device is rooted.  I don't have an app to recommend but there is probably one out there.

Answer (score 0):

if your android is rooted then this will work 100%.

androids iptable is set to DROP every packet on FORWARD policy .

to change this easily..

install AFWall+ on android...
open it .
grant su permission to it

tick wlan and eth0 for just  DHCP and DNS from list...

option-> apply..
option->enable firewall

done...